# the zero in front of the comma is not displayed

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a query in PHP that works fine so far.
For example, with a value of 0.5, I only get .5 without the zero.
How do I do that. Here is my query as an example

```
$query ="SELECT TOP 60 z.plan_auftrag, b.aunr, m.artikel, b.user_n_07,b.user_c_47, b.user_n_08, 
b.erranf_dat, b.erranf_zeit, s.a_status,m.bez_1, m.bez_2, b.user_f_25,b.user_f_26,b.user_c_48, 
b.user_c_49, b.user_c_56";
$query.=" FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z";
$query.=" JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b";
$query.=" ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr";
$query.=" JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] s";
$query.=" ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr";
$query.=" JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy] m";
$query.=" ON s.auftrag_nr = m.auftrag_nr";
$query.=" WHERE s.masch_nr = 'QTA2'"; 
$query.=" AND s.a_status IN ('V','L','U')";
$query.=" AND m.kennz = 'M'";
$query.=" AND s.eingeplant = ('M')";    
$query.=" AND b.a_typ IN ('AU','AG')";
$query.=" ORDER BY s.a_status ASC, b.errend_dat ASC, b.errend_zeit ASC";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

echo "<td>";
echo $row['aunr'];
echo "</td>";
```

This is for example the `'aunr'`.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the issue is here. Are you saying that `0.5` is being displayed as `.5` or the other way around (the title would suggest the first option, but the question itself is confusing me)? How is the value stored?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're actually storing pre-formatting strings (which seems unlikely), `.5` and `0.5` are the same as far as any database is concerned. If you want to force the leading zero to appear in your output, you can use the formatting feature of `printf()`:

```
printf("%0.1f", $row['aunr']);
```

See the [printf docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) for what the formatting template means.

Answer (score 1):

One option to solve this issue is to use the appropriate query property in the `sqlsrv_query()` call:

```
<php

...
$options = array("FormatDecimals" => true);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, null, $options);

...
?>
```

Function `sqlsrv_query` is part of PHP Driver for SQL Server and supports an optional `$options` parameter for setting additional query properties. One of these properties is `FormatDecimals` (available from version 5.6.0 of the driver), which specifies whether to add leading zeroes to decimal strings when appropriate and enables the `DecimalPlaces` option for formatting money types. The default value is `false`.

The information about all possible parameters and their default values is in the [sqlsrv_prepare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-prepare?view=sql-server-ver15) part of the documentation.

Working example:

```
<?php 
// Connection
$servername = "server\instance";
$cinfo = array(
    "UID" => 'username',
    "PWD" => 'password',
    "Database" => 'database'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Statement
$query = "SELECT CONVERT(numeric(5,2), 0.5) AS [Number]";
$options = array("FormatDecimals" => true);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, null, $options);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Fetch data
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["Number"]."<br>";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```